# Minimum number of out-shuffles required to get back to the start in a pack of $2n$ cards?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, card-games

So I'm stuck on this problem. If you perform a faro out-shuffle (i.e. a perfect "riffle shuffle" where the top and bottom cards stays in place) on a pack of 52 cards ($n=26$), you can get back the original order in 8 shuffles. Call $8$ the order for $n=26$. That's easily seen if you write the permutation in cycle notation. I checked the order for $n=1$ all the way to $n=26$. I looked for some pattern, but I found none. So my question is, is there a general formula to determine order for any arbitrary $n$? I'd be much obliged if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: The Faro out-shuffle is the following permutation:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 &\cdots& n-1 & n & n+1 & \cdots & 2n-1 & 2n\\ 1 & 3 & 5 & \cdots & 2n - 3 & 2n-1 & 2 & \cdots & 2n-2 & 2n \end{pmatrix}
$$
(Now people won't have to look up the definition.) As for how to solve it, the simple, but long way would be to pick a card, and keep track of its movements through several shuffles, and see how many shuffles it takes to get it back. Then observe that for _any_ card, unless it stays put, it's either $2, 4$ or $8$ shuffles for $n = 26$. Also see http://oeis.org/A002326.

Comment: I wrote a python script (it runs in O(n)) to track it the simple way. It's just that I am looking for a way to generate the order for really large values of $n$. It might be interesting mathematically.

Comment: @Arthur: By the simple trick of starting the numbering from zero (and ending in $2n-1$) we see that the out shuffle permutation is just multiplication by two modulo $2n-1$ (as in Kaj's answer). It is a bit unnatural in the sense that both ends of the deck correspond to the same coset, but, it works :-)

Answer (score 5):

As Arthur noted in the comments below, the out-shuffle is identical to an in-shuffle on two fewer cards.  Since the first and last cards are fixed, I will simply rename the deck to exclude those cards and focus on in-shuffling instead.  To be perfectly clear, my $1$ is really the second card and so forth.

The in-shuffle on $2n$ cards (which is an out-shuffling on $2n+2$ cards) can be represented as a permutation $\pi \in S_{2n}$ in two-line notation as follows:

$$\pi = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3  & \cdots & n && n+1 && n+2 && n+3 && \cdots &&2n\\
2 & 4 & 6  & \cdots & 2n && 1 && 3 && 5 && \cdots && 2n-1\end{pmatrix}$$

The first thing you want to do is confirm to yourself that $\pi(x) \equiv 2x \pmod{2n+1}$ for any $x \in \{1, 2, ..., 2n\}$.

From here, imagine you rewrite the two-line notation into disjoint cycle notation.  Denote $m$ as the length of the cycle to which $1$ belongs.  Can you show that $m$ is also the order of $2$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{2n+1}^\times$?  You don't need anything fancy to show this -- simply consider the previous paragraph.

Next, you'll want to show that, for any arbitrary $x \in \{1, 2, ..., 2n\}$, the length of the cycle to which $x$ belongs divides $m$.  Again, there's nothing too difficult going on here.  To get you started, we know that $\pi(x) \equiv 2x$, then $\pi(2x) \equiv 2\cdot 2x \equiv 4x$, then $\pi(4x) \equiv 2 \cdot 4x \equiv 8x$, and so forth working $\pmod{2n+1}$.  How many times must we continue until we're guaranteed to wrap around to $x$?  What can we conclude?

From here, we can simply apply the fact that the order of a composition of disjoint cycles is the least common multiple of their respective lengths.  Since all cycle lengths divide $m$, then the order of the entire permutation $\pi$ is $m$.  That is, **the number of in-shuffles required to return a deck of $2n$ cards to its original position is equal to the order of $2$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{2n+1}^\times$.**  As discussed in the first paragraph, this will be equal to the number of out-shuffles required to return a deck of $2n+2$ cards to their original position.

Unfortunately, no known closed-form exists for finding this value.  Solving $2^x = 1 \pmod{2n+1}$ is a [discrete log problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) for which polynomial-time algorithms have not been discovered (though one can apply brute-force or any of a few slight improvements on brute-forcing).

Comment: You're using the in-shuffle. That shuffle reverses the deck in $26$ moves and reverses it back again after $26$ more. The outshuffle is the one I wrote in my comment above.

Comment: According to OEIS, you do the same, but keep track of the second card instead of the first. An out-shuffle is, after all, equivalent to an in-shuffle on two fewer cards.

Comment: Quite. For the out shuffle you get the order of $2$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{2n-1}^*$. By way of sanity check: the order of $2$ modulo $51$ is eight as $2^4\not\equiv1\pmod{51}$ but $2^8\equiv1\pmod{51}$. Do fix this after you catch some sleep :-)

Comment: Thanks @Jyrki.  I'll come back to this tomorrow and patch this up. (Everything is basically correct as-is, but I could work with out-shuffles from the start).